# Womb held on to Allahs robe, Are the cloak and Robe literal?

Tags: quran, hadith, allah, aqidah

Sunnah.com mentions 3 ahadith about Allahs Robe and cloak.

https://sunnah.com/search?q=Robe+cloak

عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ قَالَ: قَالَ رَسُولُ اللهِ  صلی اللہ علیہ وسلم إن الله عزوجل لَمَّا خَلَقَ الْخَلْقَ قَامَتْ الرَّحِمُ فَأَخَذَتْ بِحَقْوِ الرَّحْمَنِ فقال:مه قَالَتْ هَذَا مَقَامُ الْعَائِذِ بك مِنَ الْقَطِيعَةِ قَالَ نعم أَمَا تَرْضَيْنَ أَنْ أَصِلَ مَنْ وَّصَلَكِ وَأَقْطَعَ مَنْ قَطَعَكِ قَالَتْ بَلَى يارب قَالَ فَذَاكَ لَكِ قَالَ أبوهريرة ثُمَّ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللهِ  صلی اللہ علیہ وسلم اقْرَءُوا إِنْ شِئْتُمْ فَہَلۡ  عَسَیۡتُمۡ  اِنۡ تَوَلَّیۡتُمۡ  اَن تفسدوا فی  الارض و تقطعوا  ارحامکم ﴿۲۲﴾  اولئک الذین لعنہم اللہ فاصمہم و اعمی  ابصارہم ﴿۲۳﴾ محمد.

ابو ہریرہ‌رضی اللہ عنہ سے مروی ہے کہ رسول اللہ صلی اللہ علیہ وسلم نے فرمایا : اللہ نے جب مخلوق کو پیدا فرمایا تو صلہ رحمی کھڑی ہو گئی اور رحمن  کے دامن کو پکڑ لیا ، اللہ نے فرمایا: رک جا اس نے کہا: یہ اس شخص کا مقام ہے جو قطع رحمی سے (تیری) پناہ میں آتا ہے ، اللہ تعالی نے فرمایا: (ہاں) کیا تم اس بات کو پسند نہیں کرتی کہ میں اس شخص کو ملاوں جو تجھے ملائے ، اور اس شخص کو توڑدوں جو تجھے توڑے؟ ( اس نے کہا: کیوں نہیں ؟ اے میرے رب) اللہ نے فرمایا: تب یہ( تمہارے لئے ہے) ابو ہریرہ‌رضی اللہ عنہ نے کہا :(پھر رسول اللہ صلی اللہ علیہ وسلم نے فرمایا:)اگر تم چاہو تو یہ آیت پڑھ لو: سورۃ محمد ﴿۲۲﴾   ﴿۲۳﴾   مکتبہ الشاملہ میں اس سے آگے تیسری آیت بھی ہے: اور تم سے یہ بھی بعید نہیں کہ اگر تمہیں حکومت مل جائے تو تم زمین میں فساد برپا کر دو اور رشتے ناطے توڑ ڈالو ۔ یہ وہی لوگ ہیں جن پر اللہ کی پھٹکار ہے اور ان کی سماعت اور آنکھوں کی روشنی چھین لی گئی ہے

Al-Silsila-tus-Sahiha#58

Status: صحیح

[www.theislam360.com](http://www.theislam360.com)

If we take both the ahadith together, the first hadith doesnt seem metaphor. Are the Robe and Cloak to  be taken literally?

Comment: Can you clarify more of what you are asking for? Can you remember more parts of the Hadith? since at least I am not familiar with such a Hadith, but still will try to find it.

Comment: Mom sleeping... she mentioned this to me... will ask her when she wakes up for fajr..  i think its available on islam360 i dont use this.

Comment: Alright, also, I would like to suggest that you put all the information you have, in the questions that way It is much easier for the answerer to give you a clear answer. Please read https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour Salam Alaykum.

Comment: Done hadith added. But couldnt find translation